# Convert PHP Time Format

Tags: php, time

I have some php code to calculate time difference and am getting difference but I need to get in some other format.

```
 $t1=9.07;
 $t2=19.03;


 list($hours, $minutes) = explode('.',$t1 );
 $startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

 list($hours, $minutes) = explode('.', $t2);
 $endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

 $seconds = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
 $minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
 $hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));
```

The output I am getting is `9:56` but I need `9:04` as output.

Comment: Where are $t1 and $t2 coming from? because it's a painfully ambiguous time format; but if $t1 is your start time, and $t2 is your end time, then `9:56` is correct

Comment: actually its coming from a csv file and i just given a sample here

Comment: but i need to get 9:04 in this format

Comment: Why do you need `9:04`, and if so how do you plan to get it? Note that it is `9:07` and `19:03`, which has a difference of `9:56`.

Comment: see i need to find out some employee work time . so if am getting exact difference like 9:04 not as 9:56 is fine . Is there any thing i have to do on the code to get that format

Comment: what does the 9 and 04 represent in your desired answer? If they represent "Number of whole hours" and "Number of minutes under the next whole hour" respectively then this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTime class to do any date calculations now that PHP 5.3 is the norm. Eg.

```
$start_date = new DateTime('2007-09-01 04:10:58');
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('2012-09-11 10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->days.' days total<br>';
echo $since_start->y.' years<br>';
echo $since_start->m.' months<br>';
echo $since_start->d.' days<br>';
echo $since_start->h.' hours<br>';
echo $since_start->i.' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->s.' seconds<br>';
```

You may set time according to your need.